# Athena: Getting a INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast 'undefined' to BIGINT when trying to add BIGINT into WHERE clause

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to run the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE order_id = 34001805542
```

And am getting a `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast 'undefined' to BIGINT when trying to add BIGINT` error.

I have tried casting the integer like this to no avail:

`WHERE order_id = TRY_CAST(34001805542 AS BIGINT)`

Comment: `34001805542` is a `BIGINT` so no need to cast it, `order_id` is a problem - Presto will try casting it to `BIGINT` and will fail. What is type of `order_id` (`SELECT typeof(order_id)...`)?  Also you can try checking actual values where conversion fails (`SELECT order_id FROM sales WHERE TRY_CAST(order_id AS BIGINT) LIMIT 10` for example)

Comment: ```order_id``` is BIGINT